# Approximating differential equation in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, initial-value-problems, maple

I have the following differential equation:
$$
y'(t) = \frac{y(t)-7t}{y(t)+t}.
$$

I would like to determine the second order Taylor polynomial that satisfies $y(-1)=3$.

I have defined the differential equation in maple as follows:
$$
L := y'(t) = \frac{y(t)-7t}{y(t)+t}
$$

I have used the following command to find the series solution:

> `dsolve({L, y(-1) = 3}, y(t), series, order = 2)`

I do get the correct solution. However as I am also calculating by hand I would like to check my results so I would like to compute $y'(-1)$ and $y''(-1)$ directly in maple. How do I do that? I have tried but it simply is not working!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want $y(1)=3$ or $y(-1)=3$? Your question seems to have a contradiction on that point.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I would like to directly compute y'(-1) and y''(-1). Now I am trying to write a small procedure but that seems farfetched. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did the rest of the comments go? A getleman helped me with some maple commands but they seem to have disappeared. Were they deleted? If so then why?

Comment: @omem How about fixing that typo?

Comment: @Gary, what typo are you referring to? And what is the -2 I see on the left side of my question? It says that my question does not show any research but I did spend quite some time searching for an answer and also trying myself.

Comment: Typo: You wrote "I would like to determine the second order Taylor polynomial that satisfies $y(1)=3$." but in your code you wrote $y(-1)=3$. So is it $y(1)=3$ or $y(-1)=3$? About the $-2$: I did not downvote your question.

Comment: Yes I see, you are correct, t=-1.

Comment: @omem So, I am asking you again. Why do not you fix the typo?

Comment: Don't know why I did not correct the typo. Well, it's corrected now.

Comment: Could someone help me with the following: if I have the differential equation given in the question how do I compute the values y'(-1) and y''(-1) using maple? I can do it manually but how do I find the values using maple?